# How do I change a vector to a vector of pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have been having this issue and I can't seem to find any resources that help me.

Basically, I have to change `vector<User>` to be a `vector<User*>` in this function:

```cpp
void promptUserAction(vector<User> &players, int playernumber, const Room rooms[], string &strCh,BadGuy bad)
{
    // tell user where they are and describes the room
    cout << (players)[playernumber] << " you are currently in " << rooms[(players)[playernumber].getIndexofCurrentRoom()]
         << endl;
    if ((players)[playernumber].getIndexofCurrentRoom()==bad.getIndexCurrentRoom())
    {
        cout<<"There is a bad guy ("+bad.getName()+") also in the room."<<endl;
    }
    //prompt user for choice
    cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl << "**********************" << endl;
    cin >> strCh;
}
```

I can't figure out how to call the function in my `main()` function correctly.

```cpp
do {
    promptUserAction(players, User::IndNextUser, rooms, UserAction, badGuy1);
```

Comment: I have no idea what this is really asking, but is all you're asking, "How do I change a `std::vector<Class>` to a side-by-side `std::vector<Class*>`, where the latter holds the address of each object within the former?

Comment: No I don't think so. I'm trying to change the vector<Class> to vector<Class*>. Not put it side by side. I trying to change it from a regular vector to a vector of pointers.

Comment: You *almost* described you want *exactly* what I just asked, so I'll state it again: Given a vector of some concrete object, you want that transformed into a vector of pointers to the same objects that are still concrete, and still reside in the original vector ? Granted, I don't begin to claim I understand *why* you want this, and the code shown gives no warrant of reason you even need it, but nonetheless, it at least *seems* that is what you're asking.

Comment: Is your problem that players in main() is a vector<User*> ? Just change the argument to promptUserAction to match and do things like players[playernumber]->getIndexofCurrentRoom()

Comment: I figured it out... If I had posted the whole issue it would have been about 500 lines but I just didn't ever change the place where i initially created the original vector. From there all I had to do was replace all the "." with "->". and change where I used the vector as a parameter the pointer of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to wrap the `players` parameter in parenthesis like `(players)` whenever you refer to it.  Change `(players)[playernumber]` to `players[playernumber]`.

In any case, nothing in the code you have shown wants a `vector<User*>`, so why do you think you need this conversion?  If you really need it (in code you have not shown), then the only way to "convert" a `vector<T>` into a `vector<T*>` is to create a new `vector` and push the addresses of the 1st `vector`'s elements into it, eg:

```cpp
vector<T> vec;
...
std::vector<T*> dest;
dest.reserve(vec.size());
for(auto &elem : vec) {
    dest.push_back(&elem);
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
vector<T> vec;
...
std::vector<T*> dest(vec.size());
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), dest.begin(),
    [](auto &elem){ return &elem; }
);
```